# Is there a way to create a second login (with user) in the Azure PaaS database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, paas

We have moved our database from a physical server to a Azure PaaS SQL database. The server login is used by the application to connect to the database. I need to create another login account with read-only access to the database. Can someone please help.

Things i have tried already.

```
CREATE LOGIN login123
WITH PASSWORD = ******* 

CREATE USER login123 
FOR LOGIN login123
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER login123
```

The above was executed successfully but when the application uses this login it gets the below error. 
"The server pricipal "login123" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context. Cannot open user default database. Login failed."

Comment: Hi,did you tried my answer? If it's helpful, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this query:

```
CREATE LOGIN login123
WITH PASSWORD = ******* 

CREATE USER login123 
FOR LOGIN login123
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER login123
```

This means that the new user only have the readonly permission for the database.

Which database the query run in, the readonly permission is for which database.

The user don't have the permission to access other database or master db.

For more details, please see:

1. [Controlling and granting database access to SQL Database and SQL
   Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins)
2. [Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you want the user both have the readonly permission to more database, you should create more user(with the same) in different database. Using one Login mapping to more users.

Here the T-SQL code, I tested and it works in Azure SQL database:

```````
USE master
CREATE LOGIN login123
WITH PASSWORD = '****' 
GO
CREATE USER login123 
FOR LOGIN login123
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = db_datareader
GO


USE Mydatabase  
CREATE USER login123 
FOR LOGIN login123
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER login123
GO

``````
```````

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Leon, Thanks a lot for your response. I am not to able to run the above query by selecting my database. I cannot run the statement "USE MyDatabase". Azure is not allowing me to run. I guess i dont have accedd to do this.

Comment: Why?  You should run it in different databases. For example, run "USE master...=db_datareater" in master db, run "USE databasename....  ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER login123" in your user DB.

Comment: I did now run it for my exact database. as per below. It is working but i need to select the database in the login options before i connect with myuser. There is no other way i guess

CREATE LOGIN mylogin 
WITH PASSWORD = 'password' 

CREATE USER myuser  
FOR LOGIN mylogin 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = mydatabase

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER myuser

Answer (score 1):

With Azure-Sql-database  You can't use a sql server login to connect to the master database
You have to put in the connection string the database that you want to access.

you can find more information on this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#non-administrator-users

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse. I tried again as per the link you have provided. I executed the below statements.

CREATE LOGIN login123
WITH PASSWORD = ******* 

CREATE USER login123 
FOR LOGIN login123

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER login123


I still cannot login via SSMS with the above login. Can only serveradmin login to the Azure database?

Comment: No if you want to access with SSMS you have to click on Options in the connect to server tab and specify the Name of the database where you create the login
Would you want some print screen ?

Comment: Hello...This actually worked for a bit. I did the below. 
1. Connect to the server and create login. Then disconnect.
2. In connect to server tab, I choose the database and then connect. Create a the user by selecting my database. provided datareader access as required.

Now, I have to always select the database when i login with my readonly user. If i try to connect directly to the server with readonly user it doesn't allow me to.

Comment: With sql authentification on Azure Sql Database you always must specify the database. Is that a problem for you ?
If you absolutely need to connetc to the server you can create an service principal application and add this to the admin group of the server and then you'll be able to connect with this credential but I think that it's better to create a Sql login with small access only what the user need.